# What are the files in a java project

Tags: java, eclipse, project

Could someone explain what the different components of a java project are? What do the different folders contain and how do they interact with each other? I've only ever written simple code in classes before, nothing really project-based.

For example, what are these files in a project folder:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You favorite search engine might get you an answer.

Comment: Right, and in the future, that answer is going to be this page.

Comment: It is now the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be new to Java I will explain in some detail about the project structure.

First of all not all Java projects would have the same folder structure. There will be some similarities, but they are not always the same.

Your Java project would have java source files (files with the .java extension) and those will reside in the `src` folder in their [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/).

Your project would depend on other libraries (Compiled Java code that others have written.. For example [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)).  They are downloadable as [jar files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/). Those jar files would reside in the `lib` folder.

The [bin directory contains the executable files](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149037/why-is-the-folder-name-bin-used-in-some-frameworks-and-languages).  For example, your Java software would have a file which you can double-click to run, or execute in a command line. Such files would go in the `bin` directory.

The build.xml file is an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build script. Ant is a [build tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) which is used to automate some aspects of building the software. [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is another widely used build tool for Java.

The `data` and `derived` directories would contain files which are specific to your project. For example `data` directory could have database files.

You have also asked how the folders interact with each-other. How the different files are used would be defined in the build.xml file in your case. That file would say which source files to compile, which are [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and where to put the `.class` files after compiling. Once you [execute the build tool](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html), it would usually build the final artifact that would be delivered to your users.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that it depends upon who set up the project. There are multiple common conventions in use; this is just one of them.

In general:

bin: Binaries. That may be compiled classfiles, or may be other binary resources in use by this project such as native code.

build.xml: Typically an ant (qv) build script for the project. Many Eclipse projects don't use ant to control their build; some do so the build can be run independently.

data: Presumably input/output data for the project. Gods only know; ask whoever's running that project.

derived: Gods only know; ask whoever's running that project.

lib: Libraries. Typically jarfiles appearing on this project's build path that can't be obtained from other projects or the overall build environment.

src: Source code. For a java project, the .java files. Occasionally other things as well.